# How to paperclip migration to active storage with expiring_url?

Tags: rails-activestorage

I don't want to remove Paperclip attributes before adding ActiveStorage attributes.

The official migration documents

For example

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  # New ActiveStorage declaration
  has_one_attached :logo

  # Old Paperclip config
  # must be removed BEFORE to running the rake task so that
  # all of the new ActiveStorage goodness can be used when
  # calling organization.logo
  has_attached_file :logo,
                    path: "/organizations/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
                    default_url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/organizations/missing_:style.jpg",
                    default_style: :normal,
                    styles: { thumb: "64x64#", normal: "400x400>" },
                    convert_options: { thumb: "-quality 100 -strip", normal: "-quality 75 -strip" }
end
```

The official documents say this task will migrate, but then you still end up trying to manually generate the `logo_url` and figuring out the expiring url if the objects are private.

```
namespace :organizations do
  task migrate_to_active_storage: :environment do
    Organization.where.not(logo_file_name: nil).find_each do |organization|
      # This step helps us catch any attachments we might have uploaded that
      # don't have an explicit file extension in the filename
      image = organization.logo_file_name
      ext = File.extname(image)
      image_original = CGI.unescape(image.gsub(ext, "_original#{ext}"))

      # this url pattern can be changed to reflect whatever service you use
      logo_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/organizations/#{organization.id}/#{image_original}"
      organization.logo.attach(io: open(logo_url),
                                   filename: organization.logo_file_name,
                                   content_type: organization.logo_content_type)
    end
  end
end
```